# onChangeText working in ReactJS and ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In ReactNative `onChangeText` is working but ReactJs seems to be not working there

Is there any solution for that?

```
<input onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})} />                                
<h1>Hi {this.state.text}</h1>
```

Comment: Instead of onChangeText, use the onChange prop. Moreover, this function gets event, so if you want the text, you need to reach event.target.value.

Answer (score 2):

There is no prop `onChangeText` for `input` (unless you rewrote it).

Also the default input for the function will be `event`.

Maybe this will work better for you:

```
<input onChange={event => this.setState({text: event.target.value})}
```

---